# Trouble with signals when inheriting from an abstract class

Tags: python, django

My app has different sort of users (parents, teachers, students) and I created a Profile abstract class to inherit from. I'm trying to use a receiver function so that whenever a user is created, a profile is also created.

In the admin page, when I try to create a Teacher Object, I need to create a User object first, but when I create a user object, I run into an error "AttributeError: type object 'Profile' has no attribute 'objects'".

I suspect this is because Profile is an abstract class, so if a User is created, it causes an error to create a Profile? If so, what's the better way to do this? I'm just trying to manually create a Teacher object in the admin page.

```
#models.py
class Profile(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=USER_TYPE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Teacher(Profile):
    user_type = 'teacher'

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: What are you trying to reach with `Profile.objects` ? class Profile did not exposes this attribute, that is what error is saying.

Comment: I'm trying to create a Teacher Object, but admin wants me to create a User first. However, when I try to create a User object, it gives me that error